# Как узнать пересеклись ли линии в Custom View Android?

Tags: android, customview

К примеру у меня есть своё кастомное View, в котором у меня реализован объект "Линия". Я могу нарисовать несколько таких линий, данные линии движутся хаотично, могут пересекаться, так вот, каким образом мне узнать, что линии пересеклись. Хотелось бы узнать более элегантный способ, чем постоянная проверка координат линий и их сравнения, т.к. при большом количестве линий и частой смене их положения в пространстве будет большая нагрузка на процессор. Хотелось бы узнать, есть ли какой-нибудь способ или паттерн, который помог бы мне реализовать это на подобие событий, т.е. если линии коснулись друг друга, то возвращался бы коллбэк и т.п. Не обязательно такое решение, можно любой другое, лишь бы не тривиальный способ описанный выше, если другого решения нету, то прошу обосновать

Comment: Судя по вашим рассуждениям вы собираетесь писать маленький 2D движок с колизиями)

Comment: Нууу, не совсем, скорее мне необходимо реализовать интерфейс для основной программы, а на пересечение линий необходимо реагировать

Comment: Я так понимаю кроме тривиального способа больше ничего нету, тогда можно закрывать вопрос, я уже реализовал по старинке

Answer (score 1):

Зачем отдельный View каждой линии? Это огромный оверхед. Рисуйте все линии на одной канве и обсчитывайте их координаты относительно друг друга и никакой особой нагрузки на процессор это не создаст.

Comment: Вы неправильно поняли, я рисую все линии в одной канве, просто описал внутри класс для линий. А если этих линий будет 1 000, что делать тогда, обсчитывать для каждой линии пересекается ли она с другими?